Mocking an authentication decorator in a Flask Pytest
I have a route and a unit test for it for my Flask application.
I want to mock the auth_func decorator, but i'm a bit lost on how to do this simply.
import pytest

from app import app


@pytest.fixture
def client():
    with app.test_client() as client:
        yield client


MOCK_TOKEN = "<some token>"


def test_get_stuff(mocker, client):

    # set the return value of the token_required decorator to be {"hello": "world"}
    mocker.patch('app.routes.stuff.token_required', return_value={"hello": "world"})

    # Call the route
    response = client.get(
        f"/stuff",
        headers={"Authorization": f"Bearer {MOCK_TOKEN}"}
    )

    assert response.status_code == 200
    data = response.json
    assert data == <some output data in json>


@api.route("/stuff", methods=["GET"])
@auth_func
def get_stuff(**kwargs) -> List[Dict]:
    try:
        # do stuff
        return jsonify(results), 200
    except Exception as e:
        raise e

I want to mock the token_require decorator, effectively making it like this route below without the @auth_func. How can I achieve this simply? The mocker.patch doesn't seem to be working as I thought it would.
@api.route("/stuff", methods=["GET"])
def get_stuff(**kwargs) -> List[Dict]:
    try:
        # do stuff
        return jsonify(results), 200
    except Exception as e:
        raise e


